# ifconfig shows interfaces and I want to delete them

Tags: linux, networking, centos-7

I'm on CentOS 7.6 and the `ifconfig -a` command shows the following 3 interfaces (not only those 3, but I want to remove those 3):

```
enp97s0f0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:d5:5e:92:09:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 95  memory 0x2c023000000-2c0237fffff

enp97s0f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:d5:5e:92:09:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 116  memory 0x2c022000000-2c0227fffff

enp98s0f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6c:b3:11:23:45:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf600000-df6fffff
```

I want to remove those three interfaces because they cause the KVM bridge to not work.

The main one is:

```
enp98s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 95.216.32.143  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 2a01:4f9:2a:20ee::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6eb3:11ff:fe23:45f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid
```

and this is the only one that I want to keep (with the `lo` interface too I think).

I've tried a lot of things to remove those three interfaces, but I can't find their configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`

If you're wondering what I am doing: This is a Hetzner dedicated server and I am trying to provide KVM Cloud VPS hosting on it. I have other 2 servers from Hetzner and they don't have those strange IPv6 interfaces.. but this one have this issue which causes the KVM bridge not to share the internet connection on the VPSs.

Comment: These are physical network interfaces. They are down. They do not have an IPv6 address. It really doesn’t get any more “removed” short of blacklisting devices. // They are super unlikely to be related to the problems you’re having.

Comment: @DanielB - What made me thinking that they are causing the issue is that I followed the exact some instructions on the other 2 dedicated servers to setup the KVM bridge and it worked fine.. They didn't have those physical network interfaces.

Comment: Maybe you should be asking your question about that. These are with very little doubt two dual-port NICs that are physically present in the system. You could use `lspci -v` to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ipv6 at all? If not, disable ipv6 system wide in kernel

```
cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
```

Append below lines in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then execute changes

```
sysctl -p
```

Reboot.

Also you can check if those interfaces are managed by NetworkManager (if you have it installed, `rpm -q NetworkManager`). Disable NetworkManager if you are not using it. (Inside your ifcfg-* file, you will have an entry like `"NM_CONTROLLED=yes/no"` change it to "no" for the interfaces that you are using.)

Hope that's all.

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but that didn't work either :/ actually adding `NM_CONTROLLED=no` broke the network.